# Rancher agent installation: systemctl not found

Tags: kubernetes, virtual-machine, rancher, systemctl, k3s

I have a rancher installation on cloud (integrated with harvester) and a couple of VM's in a local node (with K3os), created with harvester.
Now I would like to connect the K3S cluster running on a VM with rancher, but when I try to run in the VM the script of agent given to me by rancher, it goes into an error:

```
systemctl: command not found
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
When you run a VM with k3os, a k3s cluster within it is also started in the VM as mentioned before. So I was wrong choosing "Create a cluster", i should have chosen instead "import a cluster". In this way, the script you run into the VM works perfectly.